# We have a r.v. $X\sim \text{Bin}(30,0.5)$, then which one is true?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

We have a binomial random variable $X\sim\text{Bin}(30,0.5)$, then which of the following assertions is true?

- $P(X>15)=0.5$
- $P(X<15)=0.5$
- $P(X>15)>0.5$
- $P(X<15)<0.5$

**My approach**

I tried to approach this problem by the central limit theorem. Mean and variance are $15$ and $7.5$. After applying a continuity correction, I think the answer should be $P(X>15) = P(X>14.5)>0.5$ but the manual gives the 4th option as the correct answer.

Is my approach incorrect?

Please help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry,$$
P(X < 15) = \frac{1}{2} (P(X < 15) + P(X > 15)) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - P(X = 15)) < \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Hey, Alex thanks for the answer and I completely understood your explanation but why can't we solve using central limit theorem.

Comment: @RAHUlJHa Central limit theorem gives an approximation instead of an accurate relation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n=30$ is large and $p=0.5$ is far from $0$ and $1$, then $X \sim N(np,npq)=N(15,7.5)$. Using continuity correction factor:
$$P(X>15)=\Phi\left(Z>\frac{(15+0.5)-15}{\sqrt{7.5}}\right)=\Phi(Z>0.18)<0.5 \\
\ \text{or simpler:} \\
P(X>15)=P(X\ge 16)<0.5.$$
Now note:
$$P(X<15)=P(X>15)<0.5.$$

Comment: I think, we will subtract $0.5$ since it is greater than probability. Note, in continuity correction, $P(a<Y<b)=P(a-0.5<Y<b+0.5)$.

Comment: Nope, you must consider the difference between $>$ and $\ge$. Check [here](http://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-the-continuity-correction-factor/).